Large powers of the Laplacian operator in spherical coordinates
I'm wondering if MATLAB can calculate symbolically large powers of the Laplacian operator in spherical coordinates, namely

The reason why I want to do that is because I don't want to calculate myself the final expression, since it gets very complicated very fast for large powers n.
Anyone had this problem before?
I have tried to look at the MATLAB symbolic features but I didn't find anything similar. I know it can handle symbolic functions to solve differential equations, but in this case I want it to calculate symbolically large powers of an operator.

Does the power n of the operator mean applying the operator n times? If so, you can just use sym.laplacian in a loop

Thank you for your answer. Yes, it means applying the operator n times. I will try your suggestion. Do you happen to know how to do that for an arbitrary operator? I will also need that later.

Same approach, I guess? Just put it inside a for k = 1:n ... end loop. For example, this integrates the function f(x) = 2x three times
